# What are the performance differences between Promise.join Promise.all?

Tags: performance, promise, bluebird

I was combing through the [Bluebird docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html), and they recommend using `Promise.join` over `Promise.all` for concurrent discrete promises.

The documentation says

> Promise.join is much easier (and more performant) to use when you have a fixed amount of discrete promises that you want to coordinate concurrently.

However there's no explanation about the performance comment.

The only difference I see is that `.all` does the extra operation of unpacking the array. Seems like a stretch to call that "more performant" so maybe there's something else under the hood?

Any explanation would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any major performance impacts. Checkout the Fiddle here for benchmarking this:

https://jsfiddle.net/msmta/3936tnca/

```
// spread

function startSpreadTest() {
  var startTime = new Date()
  var spreadArray = []
  for(var i = 0; i < promiseCount; i++)
    spreadArray.push(Promise.delay(promiseDelay))
  return Promise.all(spreadArray).spread(function(){
    return getStopTime(startTime)
  })
}

// join

function startJoinTest() {
  var startTime = new Date()
  var args = []
  for(var i = 0; i < promiseCount; i++)
    args.push(Promise.delay(promiseDelay))
  args.push(function(){
    return getStopTime(startTime)
  })
  return Promise.join.apply(null, args)
}
```